# Postgresql Concat String

Tags: database, string, function, postgresql, concatenation

I want to create select Query in Postgresql. my code is

```
 select * into concat('production.',layer_name)  from concat('staging.',layer_name);
```

but there is a problem

```
ERROR:  "concat" is not a known variable
LINE 20: select * into concat('production.'layer_name)  from concat('...
```

I can not understand why .

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You can't specify a table's name using an expression -- it has to be a plain table name.  Also what you're doing is indicative of bad DB design.  It would be better to have a single table, and give it an extra field that could contain either `'production'` or `'staging'` -- preferably with an FK link to a master table with 2 rows, one for `production` and one for `staging`.

Comment: I agree. There shouldn't be different tables for staging, production, etc.  These either need to be separate databases, one for each environment, or have a field in one table for staging, production, etc. like the previous commenter mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`concat()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) function in Postgres (since v.9.1). Useful for string concatenation possibly involving `NULL` values. But your syntax is just gibberish to the Postgres parser. It is generally not possible to use values (or return values from a function) as identifiers in plain SQL. You would need [dynamic SQL in a plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-sql+plpgsql) for that.

But your example doesn't seem to need either. Do you want to copy rows from one table to another one? If so:

```
INSERT INTO production.layer_name
SELECT * FROM staging.layer_name
```